# Write a new file whose name is composed of strings entered from raw_input in Python

Tags: python

I want to write a new file whose name is composed of strings supplied through raw_input by the user. For instance,

```
print "What is the serial number of the site?",
_nnn = raw_input()

print "What is the brand, product or model name?",
_brand = raw_input()
```

I want to concatenate these values into the new file name. So if the user entered 001 when prompted for the serial number, that would be the first part of the file name, followed by SuperTurbo for the _brand value, etc. The new file would be named, "001SuperTurbo".

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: string concatenation is simple `new_file = _nnn + _brand`

Comment: It is completely irrelevant how you received the strings, btw. Further, you should really not learn the old Python 2 any longer but rather start off with a current Python 3. When upgrading, remember that `print` has become a function and that the equivalent of `raw_input()` is called `input()`. That said, please read a tutorial (check out docs.python.org), your question shows a very severe lack of even the most basic stuff.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

print "What is the serial number of the site?",
_nnn = raw_input()

print "What is the brand, product or model name?",
_brand = raw_input()

farmfile = _nnn + _brand
outie = open(farmfile, 'w')
outie.close()
```

Comment: Without any explanation, it's hard to know how this resolves the issue. The question already has one downvote, so you might consider deleting the question if you were able to resolve it & you don't believe it has significant value to warrant keeping this question. Questions on SO should appeal to a wider audience and not just one person.

Comment: Why are you so sure this page would appeal to only me? Seems awfully pissy to say so.

Comment: First, the question was closed as a duplicate by moderators. Second, the question doesn't contain a question. There are a bunch of requirements pertinent to you (but not necessarily helpful to others). Third, the question has five downvotes. Finally, the only answer has two downvotes and no explanation. The SO community is saying this doesn't have much value. It's not just me. Downvotes hurt your reputation. I'm only suggesting you consider removing the question if you also think this doesn't hold lasting value for the community. If you think otherwise, that's fine.